# 複数の json ファイルを読み取り、リストを作成したい

Tags: python, python3, json, jupyter-notebook

次のようなファイルが大量にあります。

#001.json

```js
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "hoge"
}
```

#002.json

```js
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "fuga"
}
```

これらを読み込み、次のようなオブジェクトを作りたいです。

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "hoge"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "fuga"
    }
]
```

for ループで append していくことで一応達成してはいるのですが、これを簡単に行う方法はありますか

```py
files = glob.glob(dir+'*.json')
print(list(files))

data = []
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        data.append(json.load(f))
print(list(data))
```

Comment: append するだけで良いのあれば、list comprehension を使うこともできます。`data = [json.load(open(f, 'r')) for f in sorted(glob.glob(dir+'*.json'))]` もっとも、これは質問欄にあるコードを約めただけですので、「簡単に」という事ではありませんけれども。

Comment: 簡単になっているとは思いますけど、それだとファイルのクローズが不確実になりませんか？

Comment: こんな記事があるようです。[Pythonメモ-03 (リスト内包表記の中でファイルをopenすることについて)](https://devlights.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/05/02/001954)

Comment: pandas 使って、`data = pd.concat(pd.read_json(f, 'index').T for f in files).to_dict('records')` でもいけます。　コード的には短くなりますが、「簡単」かどうかは不明です。

Comment: @kunif a for b in c の c の部分で一度だけ開きたいという記事はいくつか見かけたのですが、今回は a の部分で開きたいのです。万単位のファイルがあるので都度クローズが保証されないと不安になります

Comment: @magichan pandas って json 取り扱えたんですね、知らなかった　ワンライナーで行けるのは嬉しい

Comment: 希望通り上手く出来るか判りませんが、Pythonではなく前処理として`jq`コマンドを試してみてはどうでしょう？ [How to merge 2 files json in one with 1 array only for all ? thx #805](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/805)

Comment: @kunif 今回は google colab を使用しており、そこにはインストールされていないようでした。自由な環境で実行できるときは試してみます

Comment: @v..snow `file.close()` の事を考えていませんでした。一応、more_itertools に [with_iter()](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.with_iter) というメソッドがありまして、"Wrap an iterable in a with statement, so it closes once exhausted." なので、`from more_itertools import with_iter`, `data = [json.loads(''.join(list(with_iter(open(f))))) for f in sorted(glob.glob(dir+'*.json'))]` と書けます。ですが、google colab に more_itertools はインストールされていないでしょうね。。。

Comment: @metropolis with_iter というのは close 出来るイテレータを引数に取り、イテレータがすべて消費されたら close する、という理解であっていますか？

Comment: @v..snow はい、その通りです。

Comment: @metropolis  google colab 上で動き、結果も上手くいきました。もしよろしければ回答として投稿してもらえると承認します

Comment: 他の方達もおっしゃられていますが、v..snow さんが最初に書かれたコード(質問欄のコード)がもっとも確実で簡単なのではないかと思う次第です。`with_iter()`  を使う方法は外部のパッケージを使っていますし、リーダビリティがよろしくありません(list comprehension で解決するため、無理に`with_iter()` を使っていますので)。。。後ほど、参考例として回答を投稿しますが、承認はなさらないで下さい。

Answer (score 1):

more_itertools の [with_iter() メソッド](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.with_iter) を使うと以下の様に書くことができます。

```
import glob
import json
from more_itertools import with_iter

dir = './'
data = [
  json.loads(''.join(list(with_iter(open(f)))))
  for f in sorted(glob.glob(dir+'*.json'))
]
```

**[with_iter() source code](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#with_iter)**

```
def with_iter(context_manager):
    """Wrap an iterable in a ``with`` statement, so it closes once exhausted.
    For example, this will close the file when the iterator is exhausted::
        upper_lines = (line.upper() for line in with_iter(open('foo')))
    Any context manager which returns an iterable is a candidate for
    ``with_iter``.
    """
    with context_manager as iterable:
        yield from iterable
```

**註**
コメント欄にも書きましたが、`with_iter()` を使っているのは list comprehension で解決するためです。質問の意図を考えてみれば、その様な必要性はありませんし、質問者である v..snow さんが最初に書かれたコードが最も確実で簡単であるかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

例示のコードで十分簡潔だと感じましたが、2つほどご提案させて頂きます

## 1. コマンドライン引数から受け取り

- main.py

```py
import sys, json


data = []
for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(file, 'rt') as f:
        data.append(json.load(f))

print(data)
```

実行方法

```
$ ls *.json | xargs python main.py
```

## 2. os.listdir を使用

※ワイルドカード指定はできず、ディレクトリ内に読み込みたいJSONファイルしか格納されていない場合にしか使えません。このコードなら glob を使えば良いと思います…。

```py
import os


path = 'path/to/dir/'

data = []
for file in os.listdir(path):  # os.listdir(path+'*.json') はエラー
    with open(file, 'rt') as f:
        data.append(json.load(f))

print(data)
```